# Is my proof correct? (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

What I need to prove is the following:

Given the continuous function $h(x)$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and $y=\text{inf}(\{x:h(x)\geq r)$, and given the set is non-empty and  $y \in [a,b)$, then $h(y)=r$.

Proof:
For $x<y$ in $[a,b]$, we have that $h(x) < r$. Thus, $h(y-\frac{1}{n})<r$.  Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain $h(y) \leq r$.

Now, there exists a decreasing sequence $y_n$ converging to $y$ such that $h(y) \geq r$. Taking the limit gives $h(y) \geq r$. Thus $h(y)=r$, and we are done.

Does this proof appear correct?

Thank you to @KaviRamaMurthy for the initial proof using supremum instead of infimum.

Comment: The assertion “$h\left(y-\frac1n\right)<r$ when $a<y-\frac1n$” makes no sense.

Comment: The definition of $y$ is that it is the infimum of a set of points satisfying a certain property, but the infimum of a set isn't necessarily a member of that set, and hence doesn't necessarily satisfy that property.

Comment: I personally would try a proof by contradiction, assuming that $h(y)\ne r$, use the delta-epsilon definition of continuity, and derive a contradiction. But I'm not sure if there's a slicker way.

Comment: @Joe, would you mind providing a draft? I would also like to add that we state as a given that $y \in [a,b)$, meaning y would have to be in the set, no?

Comment: $y$ has to be in $[a,b)$, but is not defined to be in $\{x:h(x)\ge r\}$

Comment: I don't have time to write a draft, but if you want to try my idea, consider two cases: $h(y)=s>r$ and $h(y)=s<r$. For each, let $\varepsilon = |s-r|/2$

Comment: @Joe I can't seem to quite figure out the proof using epsilon delta, although I would really like to figure something out. If you ever find the time, I would tremendously enjoy such a proof, although for now I have another method which will suffice.